# Passing Data from ListView To TextView in different Activities, Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, bundle

I am trying to pass a ListView item to a TextView item from my MainActivity to MenuActivity, The intent successfully creates the second activity however I run issues into it when I try passing data. MainActivity.Java is a search screen that brings up the list of names of restaurants when typed in, when a user selects a restaurant it brings them to the menu page. I want their selection to be transferred to the new activity as the menu header.

MainActivity.Java

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {


             Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);

             String listItem = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
             myIntent.putExtra("restaurant" ,listItem );
             startActivity(myIntent);

        }
      }); // end of lv.setOnItemClickListener
```

MenuActivity.Java

```
public class MenuActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

// textview / menu header
private TextView menuHeader;

// parent list items
private static final String arrGroupElements[] = {"Appetizers", "Main Course", "Desserts",
    "Beverages"};

// strings for child elements
private static final String arrChildElements[][]={
    {"Appetizer 1", "Appetizer 2", "Appetizer 3", "Appetizer 4", "Appetizer 5"},
    {"Main Course 1", "Main Course 2", "Main Course 3", "Main Course 4", "Main Course 5"},
    {"Dessert 1", "Dessert 2", "Dessert 3", "Dessert 4", "Dessert 5"},
    {"Beverage 1", "Beverage 2", "Beverage 3", "Beverage 4", "Beverage 5"}      
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_screen);
    // added code
    setListAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(this));

    menuHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.articleHeaderTextView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String searchData = extras.getString("restaurant");


    menuHeader.setText(searchData);

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to pass to MenuActivity? What it looks like to me is you're just passing the string "restaurant". Is your goal to also get the listitem and pass it to the menuHeader?

Comment: Yes my goal is to pass the list item. I am new to android, and am most likely passing in the wrong parameter. What do i pass to get the listitem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {


         Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);

         String listItem = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
         myIntent.putExtra("restaurant" ,listItem );
         startActivity(myIntent);
          setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    }
  });
```

and in the menu activity override the onactivityresults method

```
    public class MenuActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

// textview / menu header
private TextView menuHeader;

// parent list items
private static final String arrGroupElements[] = {"Appetizers", "Main Course", "Desserts",
    "Beverages"};

// strings for child elements
private static final String arrChildElements[][]={
    {"Appetizer 1", "Appetizer 2", "Appetizer 3", "Appetizer 4", "Appetizer 5"},
    {"Main Course 1", "Main Course 2", "Main Course 3", "Main Course 4", "Main Course 5"},
    {"Dessert 1", "Dessert 2", "Dessert 3", "Dessert 4", "Dessert 5"},
    {"Beverage 1", "Beverage 2", "Beverage 3", "Beverage 4", "Beverage 5"}      
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_screen);
    // added code
    setListAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(this));

    menuHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.articleHeaderTextView);

}
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
          String searchData=data.getExtras().getString("restaurant");
          menuHeader.setText(searchData);
         }
```

Comment: Thank you, that has the app running without errors. However, I still cant get the name to display in the MenuActivity. I also had to change this due to an error ..  
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); -->  setResult(RESULT_OK, myIntent);

Comment: could you try to debug your code to check if the searchdata get the correct value it's better to determine where is the problem .and sorry for that you should put your intent name not intent

Comment: I dont really know how to debug with android, but I believe the problem is here. myIntent.putExtra("restaurant" ,listItem ); I am not sure how the parameters really work for the putExtra method.

Comment: You need to track your values try to check if the list item contain any value

Comment: Sorry because I am new to eclipse and android, but how would you do that?